What countries allow you to run a business while studying?
I already know that Argentina, Sweden, Estonia and probably Australia allow you to be self-employed and run a business while studying as an international student. My question is are there other countries? Because right now I am considering my options for where I will be studying and I want a country where I can keep running my business.

This is not possible in France at least not if you are staying under a student visa (by contrast, EU citizens are allowed to be students and freelance but they do not need a permit or visa in the first place).

In the UK there are restrictions around what work students are allowed to do, but work on a self-employed basis is not permitted.

This summary of EU rules might be helpful

Ask the question the other way around. Which countries allow you to study while you are there on a work visa, as long as the work pays your livelihood? That list will be very long ...

Well any other countries guys??

I found that Netherlander allows self-employment, now i have a list of 5 countries.
